# How can I learn about the values of these cmake variables?

Tags: cmake

I would like to learn more about `cmake` and decided to use the `cmake -P` together with going over its wiki, for instance, [this page](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables/Logging_Useful_Variables) "CMake Useful Variables".  So, I cut-and-pasted the page content into a file `/tmp/t1.cmake` on a notebook running Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit.

But, upon executing `cmake -P /tmp/t1.cmake` on this box, I got

```
cmake -P t1.cmake
-- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR:         /tmp
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR: /tmp
-- CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR:         /tmp
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR: /tmp
-- PROJECT_BINARY_DIR: 
-- PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR: 
-- EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH: 
-- LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH:     
-- CMAKE_MODULE_PATH: 
-- CMAKE_COMMAND: /usr/bin/cmake
-- CMAKE_ROOT: /usr/share/cmake-2.8
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE: /tmp/t1.cmake
-- CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_LINE: 49
-- CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: 
-- CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: 
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM: 
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME: 
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION: 
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: 
-- UNIX: 1
-- WIN32: 
-- APPLE: 
-- MINGW: 
-- CYGWIN: 
-- BORLAND: 
-- MSVC: 
-- MSVC_IDE: 
-- MSVC60: 
-- MSVC70: 
-- MSVC71: 
-- MSVC80: 
-- CMAKE_COMPILER_2005: 
-- CMAKE_SKIP_RULE_DEPENDENCY: 
-- CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_ALL_DEPENDENCY: 
-- CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH: 
-- CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE: 
-- CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION: 
-- CMAKE_C_FLAGS: 
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: 
-- CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE: 
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS: 
-- CMAKE_C_COMPILER: 
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER: 
-- CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC: 
-- CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX : 
-- CMAKE_AR: 
-- CMAKE_RANLIB:
```

I can understand that some of the variables are not applicable to my system and thus their values should be empty. But how about `CMAKE_SYSTEM`, `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`, `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION`, `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` etc?  They should be available, right?  I also tried  some system variables listed in the [man page](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#section_VariablesThatDescribetheSystem), e.g. `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME` etc, no go either.  If I don't know of such variables' values, how can I use them properly?

I would like to know what I am missing here.

Comment: Yes. Ruslo. What I missed from cmake documentation that I have studied so far is how you seasoned pros learned about such "insights"?  A hint or pointer would be great. I will do the digging.

Comment: For example, the man page of project command only states "Additionally this sets the variables <projectName>_BINARY_DIR and <projectName>_SOURCE_DIR to the respective values." and nothing else. I would be greatful if you could share how you learned the IMHO "undocumented" behavior of the project command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of these are set by the [`project`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aproject) command.  Unfortunately, if you add this command, you can't use CMake in scripting mode (i.e. you can't do `cmake -P`)

So, probably your best bet is to add a CMakeLists.txt alongside your `t1.cmake` with something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(ShowVariables)
include(t1.cmake)
```

then do:

```
mkdir /tmp/build
cd /tmp/build
cmake ..
```

Comment: Hi Fraser, many thanks for this handy and working tip. Much appreciated. I will accept this as answer. As the saying goes "it's better to teach a man how to fish rather than to give him a fish". I read the cmake man page carefully, but never picked out what you said above. Did you learn what the `project` command does from reading `cmake` source or from any other doc that I missed?  If the later, a pointer would be much appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately a lot of what I have learned about CMake has been trial and error.  The mailing list is great.  Even if you don't have questions, watching the list was an excellent source of info for me.